# WARNING in budgets, maximum exceeded for initial

Tags: angular, build, production, ng-build

When building my Angular 7 project with --prod, I receive a warning in `budgets`.

I have an Angular 7 project. I am trying to build it, but I keep getting the following warning:

> WARNING in budgets, maximum exceeded for initial. Budget 2 MB was exceeded by 1.77 MB

These are the chunk details:

```
chunk {scripts} scripts.2cc9101aa9ed72da1ec4.js (scripts) 154 kB  [rendered]
chunk {0} runtime.ec2944dd8b20ec099bf3.js (runtime) 1.41 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} main.13d1eb792af7c2f359ed.js (main) 3.34 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} polyfills.11b1e0c77d01e41acbba.js (polyfills) 58.2 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} styles.33b11ad61bf10bb992bb.css (styles) 379 kB [initial] [rendered]
```

What exactly are budgets? How should I manage them?

Comment: Try compressing your images in assets instead of editing the angular.json file

Comment: @Ahsan that's what I did. Still the same message. Not sure it's about assets.

Answer (score 1042, accepted):

Open **angular.json** file and find `budgets` keyword.

It should look like:

```json
    "budgets": [
       {
          "type": "initial",
          "maximumWarning": "2mb",
          "maximumError": "5mb"
       }
    ]
```

As you’ve probably guessed you can increase the `maximumWarning` value to prevent this warning, i.e.:

```json
    "budgets": [
       {
          "type": "initial",
          "maximumWarning": "4mb", <===
          "maximumError": "5mb"
       }
    ]
```

### What does **budgets** mean?

> A performance budget is a group of limits to certain values that
> affect site performance, that may not be exceeded in the design and
> development of any web project.

In our case budget is the limit for bundle sizes.

See also:

- https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3216
- https://angular.io/guide/build#configure-size-budgets
- [Performance Budgets (Keep Request Counts Low And File Sizes Small)](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/budgets)

Comment: Thanks @yurzui for your quick answer,  Is it new feature in angular 7? We didn't see this error in angular 5. Does it means we are doing something wrong?

Comment: @StackOverflow Was added in `@angular/cli@7` See also what's new in ng7 here https://blog.angular.io/version-7-of-angular-cli-prompts-virtual-scroll-drag-and-drop-and-more-c594e22e7b8c `With v7, we are also defaulting new projects to take advantage of Bundle Budgets in our CLI.`

Comment: how to optimize to decrease the used-budget size? instead of increase it...

Comment: @deadManN I guess avoiding including a whole npm package just to call one method or find alternatives with lighter foot-print or implementing your own logic just for the needed part.

Comment: In vite you can config manualChunks to split your bundles. That's easy and straight forward. But in angular it feels like a pain. ChatGPT suggested to config webpack and use a custom webpack builder. This is incredible complicated. Or use lazy loading in routes for some components, but it didn't reduced the bundle size. So I found no solution @hassan

Answer (score 19):

In my case I had to change like this, the accepted solution did not work. I am using TensorFlow.js in Angular.

```
"budgets": [
   {
      "type": "initial",
      "maximumWarning": "4mb", 
      "maximumError": "5mb"<=== instead! 
   }
]
```

Answer (score 18):

Please Open `angular.json` and check for `budgets` keyword, and increase/raise the `maximumWarning, maximumError` this should solve the issues

```
 "budgets": [
       {
          "type": "initial",
          "maximumWarning": "8mb",
          "maximumError": "8mb"
       }
    ]
```

Answer (score 12):

Go to angular.json file, under configurations->production->budgets, increase maximumWarning and maximumError more than the error is showing.

```
"configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "12mb",
              "maximumError": "12mb"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

I have set it to 12mb each to eliminate the warning and error messages from compiler.

Answer (score 3):

```
"budgets": [ { "type": "initial", "maximumWarning": "2mb", "maximumError": "5mb" } ]
```

I used this but it does not work. Then I did this:

```
"budgets": [ { "type": "initial", "maximumWarning": "20mb", "maximumError": "25mb" }, { "type": "anyComponentStyle", "maximumWarning": "20mb", "maximumError": "25mb" } ]
```

Comment: Silencing the alarm forever is not a good practice. At least set them to sane limits. I don't think you'll want your app to become a 20mb monster before the compiler warns about it.

Answer (score 1):

This resolve my issue

```
"budgets": [
   {
      "type": "initial",
      "maximumWarning": "4mb", 
      "maximumError": "5mb"<=== instead! 
   }
]
```