# Warning in budget exceeded in asset/bower_component

Tags: angular, ng-build

Getting error when doing the ng build --prod in the docker container.

"Error in budget exceeded maximum for assets/bower_components"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WARNING in budgets, maximum exceeded for initial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53995948/warning-in-budgets-maximum-exceeded-for-initial)

Comment: @MichaelD I tried with the above link. but getting same error. this is my budget in angular.json "budgets": [ { "type": "initial", "maximumWarning": "10mb", "maximumError": "10mb" }, { "type": "anyComponentStyle", "maximumWarning": "6kb", "maximumError": "10kb" } ]