# Getting error - Error: bundle initial exceeded maximum budget. Budget 5.00 MB was not met by 6.05 MB with a total of 11.05 MB

Tags: javascript, angular, optimization, build, angular-cli

I am facing an issue while deploying the code and I get

```
 Warning: bundle initial exceeded maximum budget. Budget 2.00 MB was not met by 9.05 MB with a total of 11.05 MB.

 Error: bundle initial exceeded maximum budget. Budget 5.00 MB was not met by 6.05 MB with a total of 11.05 MB.
```

My budgets object in angular.json file is -

```
"budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "2mb",
              "maximumError": "5mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "6kb"
            }
          ]
```

And I tried various combinations as referred to in these sites -

> [WARNING in budgets, maximum exceeded for initial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53995948/warning-in-budgets-maximum-exceeded-for-initial)
>
> [Warning: budgets: initial exceeded maximum budget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65363248/warning-budgets-initial-exceeded-maximum-budget)

I tried -

```
    "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "12mb",
              "maximumError": "14mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "9kb",
              "maximumError": "2mb"
            
            }
          ]
```

But it did not help. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue with the following combination -

```
"budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "7mb",
              "maximumError": "14mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "6kb"
            }
          ]
```

Also, it was present at multiple places in angular.json file . So added the same in multiple places.