# Angular - Error: initial exceeded maximum budget. Budget 5.00 MB was not met by 197.06 kB with a total of 5.19 MB

Tags: angular

When I was building my Angular 12 project I got this error:

> Error: initial exceeded maximum budget. Budget 5.00 MB was not met by 197.06 kB with a total of 5.19 MB

My angular.json:

```
"budgets": [
    {
        "type": "initial",
        "maximumWarning": "4mb",
        "maximumError": "5mb"
    },
    {
        "type": "anyComponentStyle",
        "maximumWarning": "2kb",
        "maximumError": "4kb"
    }
],
```

Yet I still have the error.

How do I resolve this?

Thank.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WARNING in budgets, maximum exceeded for initial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53995948/warning-in-budgets-maximum-exceeded-for-initial)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Your budget is 5MB but your bundle size is greater than that (5.19MB) which is causing this error. You need to increase your `maximumError` budget in you `angular.json` as follows:

```
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "4mb",
              "maximumError": "6mb"
            },
```

You can also follow few techniques to reduce the bundle sizes as much as possible:

- Use `ng build --prod --build-optimizer`. For newer versions, this is done by default with `ng build --prod` or `ng build`
- Use module `lazy loading` and modularize your application as much as possible.
- You can also use Ivy rendering engine it offers better bundle sizes
- Make sure your 3rd party dependenciess are tree shakeable.
- Use 3rd party tools like `webpack-bundle-analyzer` to see what is causing bloat in your modules
- You can also check if you files are gzipped or not

Comment: ng build --prod , this is also deprecated. ng build works just fine

Answer (score 11):

I think you need to define your size boundaries in the CLI configuration file, `angular.json`.

```
{
  ...
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      ...
      budgets: [
        {
          "type": "initial",
          "maximumWarning": "4mb",
          "maximumError": "5mb" // <==== change this number because your app is 5.19 MB now.
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Reference: https://angular.io/guide/build#configure-size-budgets

Comment: Perfect! Depending on the error, since my build was a total of 5.26 MB, I changed it to 6mb.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the **limits** set by the framework. To do this, you must edit the **angular.json** file located at the root of your project.

Look for the block named **budgets**. The `maximumWarning` value corresponds to the threshold above which the warning message is displayed. The value `maximumError` corresponds to the triggering of the error.

```
"budgets": [
       {
          "type": "initial",
          "maximumWarning": "2mb",
          "maximumError": "5mb"
       }
    ]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at the other answers that were given before. Your approach is mentioned there already. In order to keep the site clear and make it easy to find answers, we try to avoid double answers.